# rewrite SQL query to HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I've SQL query:

```
SELECT
    tag.id, 
    tag.description, 
    tag.`name`, 
    COUNT(question_has_tag.question_id)
FROM
    question_has_tag
INNER JOIN
    question
ON 
    question.id = question_has_tag.question_id
INNER JOIN
    tag
ON 
    question_has_tag.tag_id = tag.id
GROUP BY
    tag.id
```

All works good.
But I need to rewrite it to HQL, some one have any idea?
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
list = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT " +
            "t.id, " +
            "t.description, " +
            "t.name, " +
            "COUNT(q.id) " +
            "FROM Tag t INNER JOIN Question q ON t.id = q.id " +
            "GROUP BY t.id").getResultList();
```

Sorry it not all information, I've 3 table tag, question and question_has_tag (auto created by hibernate) tag and question has ManyToMany relations

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Question> questions;
```

and

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "question_has_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
list = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT " +
            "t.id, " +
            "t.description, " +
            "t.name, " +
            "COUNT(q.id) " +
            "FROM Tag t JOIN t.questions q" +
            "GROUP BY t.id").getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks! :) It's what I need!